# Word or phrase for a combination of an estimated and actual value

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase a for combined value of an estimate and actual value.

I work on an ecommerce platform and we calculate shipping prices. The calculated shipping price is billed directly to the customer. Later when the shipment has been fully processed we get the invoice containing the actual shipping cost.

Sometimes the actual value does not exist yet, because invoices are put through on a monthly basis. I now need a word or phrase or something to say 'this value is the actual value, and where the actual value does not exist yet, we use the estimate'.

Example for clarification:

```
| Order | Estimate | Actual | ??   |
| ----- | -------- | ------ | ---- |
| #123  | 1.2      |        | 1.2  |
| #456  | 2.3      | 2.45   | 2.45 |
| #789  | 1.2      | 1.5    | 1.5  |
```

Comment: *Tentative*, *provisional* value may be used.

Comment: It may be acceptable just to list one column, the value used, with a note such as 'an asterisk shows that an estimated value is used as the actual value is not available at this point in time'. Otherwise, I don't think your version ('this value is the actual value, and ,,,') needs improvement. 'Figure used' is an accurate if inelegant column header.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The difference between the actual and the estimate is important, because if there is significant difference it means we're billing the customer too much or too little for shipping. we can tune the estimate according to this data. In this sparse sample we can see that we're billing too little to the customer, and we should up our estimate. The third column is needed because we're using that data for other other columns (not shown here). For example the average shipping cost per order, would be the third column divided by the number of orders.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth a good suggestion to add a reference with a better explanation, i still need some way of naming this column - perhaps provisional would be a good term.

Comment: I feel this doesn't really refer well to the definite figures. But it's your table.

Comment: Whatever word you put on the top of the last column, it will need to be explicitly defined somewhere in the document. There is no word that will by itself, without being explicitly defined within the document, convey the precise meaning you have in mind.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Since this site is concerned with the English language and not User Interfaces _per se_, please include a sample sentence so we get an idea of how your word would be used in prose. For example, you might have "The ___ figure includes a subjective amount arising from expectations on how the price would change." The empty line serves as a placeholder for the word.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest something like:

```
| Order | Estimate | Current | 
| ----- | -------- | ------- |
| #123  | 1.2      | (1.2) * |
| #456  | 2.3      | 2.45    | 
| #789  | 1.2      | 1.5     | 

 * - Cost is not yet finalized
```

Comment: This is not, strictly speaking, an answer to the question as posed, but it is a workaround that is better for the OP's purposes that trying to find a single word that doesn't exist. For that matter, it is not clear why the OP insists on listing the estimates in the cases in which the actual value is known; the best solution would be to just list one amount, with the understanding that it can be presumed to be actual, unless it is asterisked as a mere estimate.

Comment: Not sure why brackets are used; they normally indicate negative values in accountancy, but they seem to be used for provisional values here. I suggest you explain what notation you are using.